# picking 10 different numbers from 1-50

Tags: probability

Stage 1: picking randomly 10 different numbers from 1-50 and writing them down.

Stage 2: Then, randomly, picking 10 other different numbers from 1-50.

What is the probability that the sum of the numbers in stage 2 will be equal to the sum of the

Numbers in stage 1?

I tried to solve but got too much options and got stuck.
I would glad to hear any approach

Comment: Are repetitions allowed at each stage? Can you repick what you have picked in Step 1 in Step 2? For example, the numbers in step 1 may be $1,1,14,1,26,...$ and the numbers in Step 2 may be $14, 14, 1, 49, ...$ right?

Comment: An exact expression sounds very difficult. If I really needed an approximate answer, a computer simulation sounds like the most feasible approach.

Comment: @LordSoth - i guess you can.

Comment: @LordSoth He says "different," so presumably, repetition not allowed, but the "10 other different" is unclear whether that is a disjoint 10 or not.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - and an approximate answer by hand could be done? if it impossible to get an exact one by hand.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews -"10 other different" - i guess they can be picked again as stage 1 , randomly. btw, why i can't press "enter"? it submits my comment.

Comment: @getter: If I really needed an estimate, I would start with a crude approximation for the distribution of the sums, assume independence (!), and come up with something not unreasonable for $n=200$. The number $50$ is kind of small, unfortunately.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - i will try to think more about it. thanks any way!

Comment: Convolutions are often used in such problems, i.e. 'the number of ways to get 1 dollar from $k$-cent coins', but this one seems too hard.

Comment: For a credue approximation, use the Central Limit Theorem. It's not too good with $n=50$ but will give you a crude approximation.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove all worry about repetition, so make it "Roll 10 50 sided dice and add up the numbers.  Roll them again and add up the numbers.  What is the chance the two totals agree?" it is easy to get an approximate value (up to roundoff error) from Excel.   I get $0.006135$  I suspect forcing no duplicates within each batch of 10 will not change things very much.

Comment: Thanks but im trying to get a good approximation without computer.

Comment: @user64370:  I doubt there is a reasonable hand approach.  You would have to use the normal approximation for the sum, which is easy enough to compute.  Then you would like to square it and sum at intervals of $1$, but I don't know a good way to approximate that.

Answer (score 0):

If repetitions are allowed between the two stages, you can find the probabilities of each of the sums from 55 to 455, square them, and add them. That's tedious by hand, though.